# C# WinForms Encryption with a Password

Tags: c#, winforms, encryption

I have a WinForms app I am working on, basically at the moment I have some data that I create using forms/listboxes/textboxes, this data is then encrypted with a ecryption password to a text file.

I have this all working smooth and awesome, I just wanted to know if using this method is secure, as in is it secure having a textfile with this encryption method(TripleDES algorithm):

```
        //Encryption Method
        public string EncryptString(string Message, string Passphrase)
    {
        byte[] Results;
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] TDESKey = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(Passphrase));
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDESAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        TDESAlgorithm.Key = TDESKey;
        TDESAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        TDESAlgorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        byte[] DataToEncrypt = UTF8.GetBytes(Message);
        try
        {
            ICryptoTransform Encryptor = TDESAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor();
            Results = Encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(DataToEncrypt, 0, DataToEncrypt.Length);
        }
        finally
        {
            TDESAlgorithm.Clear();
            HashProvider.Clear();
        }
        return Convert.ToBase64String(Results);
    }


    //Decryption Method
    public string DecryptString(string Message, string Passphrase)
    {
        byte[] Results;
        System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] TDESKey = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(Passphrase));
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDESAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        TDESAlgorithm.Key = TDESKey;
        TDESAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        TDESAlgorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        byte[] DataToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(Message);
        try
        {
            ICryptoTransform Decryptor = TDESAlgorithm.CreateDecryptor();
            Results = Decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(DataToDecrypt, 0, DataToDecrypt.Length);
        }
        finally
        {
            TDESAlgorithm.Clear();
            HashProvider.Clear();
        }
        return UTF8.GetString(Results);
    }
```

Comment: Question should be more appropriate in CodeReview StackExchange

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend AES encryption over 3DES any day of the week.  Your file will definitely be secure, and physical access to the file is more important.  However, if you want to use the industry standard in security than have a look at this link.

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/769741/csharp-aes-bits-encryption-library-with-salt